# MYSQL Auto Populate Field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with fields 'personAssigned' and 'dateAssigned' which will get updated a few different times. What I would like to do is add 3 more fields and have them automatically update, 'originalPersonAssigned', 'originalDateAssigned', and 'originalAssignmentDate'. Is there an easy way to do this just with MYSQL? It's working with a PHP site and I should be able to use that to make the updates, but I'm thinking that there could be an easy way to handle this on the database end.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your version of MySQL. If it is >= 5.0.2 then you can use a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried triggers? I think since MySQL 5 triggers have been available to do just this sort of thing. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

If this is only updated once, this would work, but if it is possible to assign new people to the record, you might want to use the trigger to create a related assignment history record or something.